# Need help on setup alluxio in single node

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, alluxio

I am trying to setup alluxio on my local machine .Followed the alluxio doc

http://www.alluxio.org/docs/master/en/Running-Alluxio-Locally.html

Able to see the service .But getting error while checking on localhost:19999

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /home. Reason: Server Error

Caused by:
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alluxio requires Java version 7 or higher. Here is more information on the requirements: http://www.alluxio.org/docs/master/en/Getting-Started.html

Some patch versions of Java 8 was not compatible with Alluxio 1.2, but that issue was fixed in Alluxio 1.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Issue due to java version .I have used the alluxio latest version fixed the problem.

If you are using alluxio 1.2 then should use java 7 .